# How can I Fetch all the movies from API in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to fetch all the movies data in API when my movie app starts

I tried using fetch function I used in search box ,to see If the data is correctly getting fetched I am tying to see it on 'console.log', but it throws an error.

**Error Description:**

> (intermediate value) is not iterable
> TypeError: (intermediate value) is not iterable

**Here is what I tried:**

```
const fetchMovies = async () => {
  const [res] = await fetch(`${API_URL}`);
  const dat = await res.json();
  console.log(dat);
};

useEffect(() => {
  fetchMovies();
}, []);
```

Comment: `await fetch(\`${API_URL}\`)` data type is not iterable. maybe object type. using `{ res }`

Answer (score 4):

The response from `await fetch` is not an array but rather an object so you got the error.
Remove the square bracket - [] and you will be fine.

```
const fetchMovies = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`${API_URL}`);
    const dat = await res.json();
    console.log(dat);
}
```

You can read more about fetch here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 1):

you can simply resolve the Promise using `.then`

```
const fetchMovies = async () => {
        await fetch(`${API_URL}`)
        .then(res => {
           return res.json();
        })
        .then(resp => console.log(resp, 'movies'))
        .catch(err => console.log(err, 'error'))
}
useEffect(() => {
   fetchMovies() 
}, []);
```